# Visual Force Page not Displaying in Portal (Community) Only, but visible on Internal

Tags: visualforce, community, salesforce1-app

I have a certain page that does not display in the Portal, but it does display on the Internal site. I've modified the permissions and made visible to the communities, but still no luck. Could someone give me some amazing advice to resolve this issue?

The Visual Force page references a Standard Controller and Extension Controller.

Comment: what do you mean when you say does not display does it show insufficient privilege / other error message / blank page. Are you viewing this in a salesforce1 app?

Comment: I figured out how the occurs now, the page needs to direct to Office/apex/.... but instead the page is Office/... Do you know how to apply redirects in salesforce?

Answer (score 6):

In order for a Community user to see a Visualforce page, two things have to happen.
First, the page has to be exposed to the Community, this is done from:
Communities > Manage Communities > Force.com > Public Access Settings > Enable Visualforce Page Access

Second, the page has to be exposed to the profile of the community user, this is done from:
Setup > Manage Users > Profile > Click on Profile Name > Visualforce Page Access

Remembering to do both is usually the gotcha.

Comment: I applied this but, the page still does not display in Salesforce1 app

Comment: Didn't know that you wanted SF1, your question says Community.  For SF1,  you need to make sure the page is enabled for mobile apps.  Edit from the Setup > Develop > Pages and check the box.  Ideally,  you should optimize the page for mobile display as well.

Comment: My apologies, I initially believe that was a community issue, because the page was not visible in both App and Desktop. You answer help fix the desktop issue, however, the page still does not display for SalesForce1 app.

Comment: Do you have the page configured as a Visualforce Tab? And is that tab exposed in the navigation of the Community?

Comment: Yes they have already been applied

Comment: Not sure what else it could be.  You mentioned it works internally, but not in the community. So where are you at now? Internal user, in Web UI - YES, Internal User, in Community - Yes, Internal user, SF1 Mobile - Yes and Community User, SF1 Mobile - No??

Comment: Correct
SF1 Mobile when within the Portal, but works Internally